# Convert NSString to UInt8 in a function in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, nsdata, uint8t

I'm creating a Swift app in Xcode that sends a command to a BLE adapter in order to make the LED's connected to it change to a different colour.

As I've established from a reply to a previous post on SO, I have to send command in terms of hex integers in an array. I'm using the following code in order to do this:

```
let bytes : [UInt8] = [ 0x52, 0x13, 0x00, 0x56, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAA ]
let data = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: bytes.count)
```

Therefore, this requires a UInt8 form as suggested above.

However, I'm trying to use sliders as colour pickers on my Swift app in order to set the R, G, and B colours of the LED strip connected to the BLE receiver. In order to do this I have created three sliders for R, G and B respectively, setting the minimum value of each to 0 and the max to 255 (since 255 converts to FF in hex). I'm then using the following function to convert these to hex form for me to implement in the command above.

```
func colorToHex(input: Int) -> UInt8 {
    var st = NSString(format: "%2X", input)
    return st
}
```

The problem with this is the fact that I must return a UInt8 value back again. Since 'st' is an NSString, Xcode throws an error of 'NSString not convertible to UInt8'.

I'm fairly new to Swift. The question here is, **how do I get the function to return a UInt8 value how do I get it to form a UInt8 value?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question is unclear. when the input is `255`, what you want is `255` as `UInt8`? or `[70, 70]`(`[0x46, 0x46]`) that is CString representation of  `"FF"`?

Comment: My apologies about the unclear question here. What I want, for example, is if the slider is moved to the maximum (255) then I want it to be converted to 0xFF in some way so it can be added to the bytes array. Similarly, if it was set to 150 on the slider, it would be converted to 0x96 such that it can be entered also into the bytes array. It needs to be in UInt8 form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `NSString` or `Int`. If `redSlider` is your `UISlider` with minimum value 0 and maximum value 255 then you can just compute

```
let redByte = UInt8(redSlider.value)
```

and use that in your `bytes` array:

```
var bytes : [UInt8] = [ 0x52, 0x13, 0x00, 0x56, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAA ]
bytes[0] = redByte // Assuming that the first array element is for red.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would this make red a hex value?

Comment: @BensTechTips: That question makes no sense. `0x64` and `100` are just two different ways to write the *same* number. Try `let x = 0x64; println(x)` ! – The above code converts a `Float` (in the range 0 .. 255) to an `UInt8`, and that is all you need.

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks for this! It took me a while to work this out! I guess you're saying that I could just enter the decimal values (e.g. 255) and it would be entered into the array. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just

```swift
func colorToHex(input: Int) -> UInt8 {
    return UInt8(input % (Int(UInt8.max) + 1))
}



NSString(format: "%2X", colorToHex(25))  // "19"

NSString(format: "%2X", colorToHex(254)) // "FE"

NSString(format: "%2X", colorToHex(255)) // "FF"

NSString(format: "%2X", colorToHex(256)) //  "0"
```

If I were you, I will use  NSString(format: **"%0x"**, colorToHex(25)) //  "19"
In your case you have space, if the number has one symbol

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this seems to also result in an error too. 'Binary operator % cannot be applied to operands of type Int and (UInt8)'